# JS Clear text for next output

Tags: javascript

The code below jumbles up a phrase and then asks the user to rearrange into the right logical order, when the correct phrase is entered the code outputs 'right answer' and then outputs the second question, But with the output, 'right answer' still showing. How can I clear it for the next question?

Thx Pav

```js
var currentQuestion = 0;

var words = 
        [
    ['how', 'are', 'you', 'today?'],
    ['what', 'would', 'you', 'like', 'for', 'breakfast?'],
    ['what', 'would', 'you', 'like', 'for', 'tea?']
];

var correctInput = [
    ['how are you today?'],
    ['what would you like for breakfast?'],
    ['what would you like for tea?']
];


function showQuestion(i) {
    if(i < words.length) {
        document.myForm.textinput.value = '';
        newWords = words[i].slice(0);
        shuffle(newWords);
        var el = document.getElementById('phrase');
        el.textContent = newWords.join(' ');
    }
}

function setup() {
    showQuestion(currentQuestion);
    var form = document.getElementById('myform');
    form.addEventListener('submit', checkAnswer, false);
}

function checkAnswer(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');
    if (document.myForm.textinput.value == correctInput[currentQuestion]) {
            elMsg.textContent= "right answer";
            currentQuestion++;
            showQuestion(currentQuestion);
    } else {
        elMsg.textContent= "wrong answer";
    } 
}

function shuffle(newWords) {
    var counter = newWords.length, temp, index;
    while (counter > 0) {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        counter--;
        temp = newWords[counter];
        newWords[counter] = newWords[index];
        newWords[index] = temp;}
    return newWords;}

setup();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title>  
</head> 
<body>  
    <form  name="myForm" id ="myform">
        <div id ="phrase"></div>    
        <input type = "text" id = "textinput"> 
        <button id="myBtn">Click here</button>
        <div id ="feedback"></div>
    </form>
    <script src = "phraseScrambler.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works as specified for me in Chrome. What does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
document.getElementById('feedback').text = '';
```

at the point where you want to clear 'Right Answer'.

You could tie this to a onKeyUp event listener on the text box.  That way, when the user starts typing the next answer it will clear the 'Right Answer'.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an event listener to the input field like this

```
<input onfocus='document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "";'>
```

This will clear the feedback every time the input is focused.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide both messages after 3 seconds.

```
if (document.myForm.textinput.value == correctInput[currentQuestion]) {
        elMsg.textContent= "right answer";
        currentQuestion++;
        showQuestion(currentQuestion);
} else {
    elMsg.textContent= "wrong answer";
} 
setTimeout((function (elMsg) { return function () {
    elMsg.textContent = '';
}})(elMsg), 3000)
```